# Calling Rest API using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to call REST API using apache camel but i got exception

org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[http://devloyalty.darkwing.io/api/test_loyalty] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[direct:start]] -> [SetHeader[CamelHttpMe... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: **"my_url_here"** due to: No component found with scheme: http

Sample Code is

```
public class RestApiRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("direct:start").
                    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET")).
                    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/plain")).
                    to("my_url");
                }
            }
```

and

```
 public void restApiTest(){
    RestApiRouteBuilder restApiRouteBuilder = new RestApiRouteBuilder();
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try{
        camelContext.addRoutes(restApiRouteBuilder);
        camelContext.start();

        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        String headerValue = "text/plain";

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", headerValue);

        Object result = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:start", null, headers, String.class);
        Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);
        String response = ExchangeHelper.convertToType(exchange, String.class, result);
        System.out.println("Response : "+response);


    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("The Exception is : " + e);
    }
}
```

also maven dependency for camel http

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `my_url` should start with either `http4` or `https4` as you use `camel-http4`. You can also register the `org.apache.camle.component.http4.HttpComponent` as `http` in Camel via `camleContext.addComponent("http", new HttpComponent());`

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner its working